# Jquerymobile and jquery ui data icon conflict

Tags: jquery-mobile

In my web app, I have a page where I use autocomplete widget from jQuery UI. 
I link to jQuery Mobileand jQuery UI CSS from this page.

```
link rel="stylesheet" href="Styles/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.css"
type="text/css"  link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
href="Styles/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css"
```

when I do this, my jQuery Mobile data-icons dont show at all. I just see a black hole in place. The other pages where I refer to only the jQuery Mobile have no issues. they display the data-icons fine.

Any idea as to what I could be doing wrong?

Answer (score 5):

Put the jQuery UI css link BEFORE the jQuery mobile css and should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try linking your Javascripts in the followng order:

```
<script src="custom-scripting.js"></script>
<script src="jquery-mobile.js"></script>
```

If this doesn't help, try using the custom selector in your code `:jqmData()`, as it automatically incorporates namespaced data attributes into the lookup when they are in use. For example, instead of calling `$("div[data-role='page']")`, you should use `$("div:jqmData(role='page')")`, which internally maps to `$("div[data-"+ $.mobile.ns +"role='page']")` without forcing you to concatenate a namespace into your selectors manually specially for your `data-icons`

Answer (score 0):

jQuery mobile shows the icon through a background-image and position CSS declaration, it's likely you have CSS that is overriding those styles.

To find your issue, use your debugger, Chrome's debugger is especially useful, under **Computed Style** look for the **background-image/position** style and the CSS class in conflict. Then you can see which class is winning and the actual value, if you see a black box you may very well just have a bad url to the image - which you can identify here as well by following the image link on the CSS style and seeing if that image really exists.

Also I don't see your < and > brackets around your CSS declaration, correct me if I'm wrong but I think you're supposed to link to each css file with a separate tag:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="Styles/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.css" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Styles/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.8.16.custom.css">
```